# How to email the contents (both image and content) of .mht files in php?

Tags: php, email, mhtml

Need to read an mht file and process it. Send an email with the processed content. Have referred library MhtToHtml. But its not working.

Comment: What do you mean by "processed content". Did you try to load the .mhtml file and look at via ```var_dump``` ? You may see something you can work with.

Comment: @paskl I have read the content the .mht files and replaced some of the hardcoded content with the dynamic data. Referring this dynamic content as processed data. Also saved this dynamic content to a temproary processed .mht file